Cannot understand what data to put on axis and legends Chart:
Whenever I am trying to put a data on chart, I stuck up with a nothing meaningful. I found out that I cannot use Legends, Axis etc to create a meaningful chart.
My Question is:
A) how to put data in a table so that visualizations tool in excel or power-bi correctly plot the same in the chart:
B) Define basic elements of charts of which understanding is necessary to create charts.
I had data of of a project. I was presenting Description of Four Quarter on X-Axis and Cost of each quarter on Y-Axis. But X-Axis, Y-Axis and Legends confused me a lot so i could not make desired chart.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
